# How to pass parameters in SSRS

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services

I'm pretty new to SSRS and have got stuck on passing parameters. Currently I'm doing the following:

```
ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["serverPath"] + "MyReport";
List<ReportParameter> paralist = new List<ReportParameter>();                
ReportParameter reportParam1 = new ReportParameter("LocationId", txtLocationId.Text);
ReportParameter reportParam2 = new ReportParameter("PrdAcctId", txtProductAccountId.Text);
ReportParameter reportParam3 = new ReportParameter("FromDate", frmdt);
ReportParameter reportParam4 = new ReportParameter("ToDate", todt);
ReportParameter reportParam5 = new ReportParameter("IntAmt", todt);
paralist.Add(reportParam1);
paralist.Add(reportParam2);
paralist.Add(reportParam3);
paralist.Add(reportParam4);
paralist.Add(reportParam5);
ReportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(paralist);
```

This works fine when the no. of parameters are set. But in some cases the no. of parameters will be decided at run time based on what user inputs.

Now I'm at a loss on how to make the no. of parameters flexible in the .rdl file. For example there can be n number of FromDate and ToDate and corresponding IntAmt as per user input.

I'd appreciate any help on this and Thanks in advance.

Comment: check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3215350/rdl-is-it-possible-to-have-optional-parameter-or-force-default-value-to-null

Comment: and also another one: http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/egiardina/archive/2007/06/26/sql-server-reporting-services-optional-parameters.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the effort Davide but in my case the no. of parameters is not set. Passing null is not an issue. User may input just one FromDate, ToDate and IntAmt or he may input several. What I'd like is to access all these is SSRS. I think concatenating these values in string and then splitting them in SSRS might work

Comment: How are you able to have a variable number of parameters in your SSRS report?  The number of parameters in the report is usually driven by the number of parameters in the underlying query or stored proc.  How have you been able to overcome that?  (Or is your question because you have not been able to?)

Answer (score 0):

You can call the GetParameters method to get all the current report parameters and loop through them to see what each is and the various properties of each:

Start with:

`ReportParameterInfoCollection param = ReportViewer1.ServerReport.GetParameters();`

Comment: The no. of parameters is not set. It can be 2 or 4 or 6 or.... based on user input.

Comment: Right, but calling GetParameters will return a collection of the parameters, which you can inspect to see which ones were set and what their values are. Or am I not understanding your problem?

Comment: I think the confusion is because of the word 'SET'. Let me explain the scenario: User can enter n number of values through UI. These values I've to send to the report as parameters. Now since the no. of values may differ I can't declare a fixed no. of parameters in .RDL file.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following, it works - replace index 0 with the ordinal value of your parameter:

```
if (this.rptView.ServerReport.GetParameters()[0].Values.Count > 0)
{
    string parvalue = this.rptView.ServerReport.GetParameters()[0].Values.ToString();
    paramList.Add(new ReportParameter("ReportName", parvalue));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to your question. Our main page redirects to the report rendering page using `window.href` and passes the parameters as query string.

Note: This is VB.Net code which you can convert to equivalent C# code

**CODE BEHIND**

```
Public Function GetParametersList(ByVal reportRDLName As String) As List(Of String)
    'Get these values from database. Following is a sample
    Dim parametersList As New List(Of String)()
    parametersList.Add("plantcd")
    parametersList.Add("CountID")
    Return parametersList
End Function

Public Function GetReportPath(ByVal reportRDLName As String) As String
    'Get these values from database. Following is a sample
    Dim reportPath As String = "/MyFolder/MyModule/"
    Return reportPath
End Function

Protected Overrides Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

    '--------------------------------------------------------
    Me.EnableViewState = True

    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then

        vwreports.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = New MyCustomReportServerCredentials
        vwreports.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ProcessingMode.Remote
        vwreports.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = New Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("MyReportServer"))



        Dim reportRDLName As String = Request.QueryString("rname").ToString()
        Dim parametersList As List(Of String) = GetParametersList(reportRDLName)
        Dim reportPath As String = GetReportPath(reportRDLName)

        Dim countOfParameters As Integer = parametersList.Count
        Dim parms As ReportParameter() = New ReportParameter(countOfParameters - 1) {}
        Dim iterationCount As Integer = 0

        For Each parameterName As String In parametersList
            Dim parameterValue As String = Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString(parameterName))
            If Not [String].IsNullOrEmpty(parameterValue) Then
                parms(iterationCount) = New ReportParameter(parameterName, parameterValue)
                iterationCount += 1
            End If
        Next

        vwreports.ServerReport.ReportPath = reportPath + reportRDLName
        vwreports.ServerReport.SetParameters(parms)
        vwreports.ShowParameterPrompts = False
        vwreports.ServerReport.Refresh()


    End If
End Sub
```